# Power BI Report with Bridge Table

Tags: sql, excel, database, powerbi, report

I am trying to use Power BI with my SQL DB. We have a three layer structure

1. A Main table, with information about the year and unique key for each firm
2. A bridge table which an information about the type of the firm
3. Many end Tables with information about sales and stuff

On some occasions these end tables are jointly used by different firm types and some only by one firm type.

When I load the tables into Power BI all the relationships are correctly imported and I was expecting no issue to create a summary table like Sum(Var) by Year, even though I am getting the Var from an end table and the Year from the main table. However they show the same sum for all years.

I am having a hard time creating a MWE and I do not have access to a remote server.

This picture shows the structure, which is similar to our data base, I did not add the type column. I now created bi directional realtion with the end Tables

[image: data model]

Basically I just created a MWE with this data split into 4 tables. I simplified the End tables to just be 1 and 0 and added a third firm

[image: raw data]

When taking the sums of X and Y, I am getting the same value and I would have expected 2 in 2018 and 1 in 2019 for X and 1 in 2018 and 2 in 2019 for Y

[image: Aggregation]

I also tried to merge the Year into the bridge table when loading the data, but I still get the wrong results.

I find many post about wrong totals etc. and needing to use different measures, but I do not have any complicated calculations just the sum of the raw data per year.

Anything else I can do to clarify my question? Should i create a new one?
I could add the raw data as a csv/xlsx file(s)

thx for the answer which I can accept later given that it solves my MWE, but somehow it does not solve my original problem. As explained in the comment here is my data model:

[image: original data model]

I am using the Import function from an MS SQL Data Base
and your DAX Code

```
dax1 = sumx(unternehmen; RELATED(at_sonstiges[abschluss_erwartet]))
```

Comment: For Year to affect X and Y, the relationships with those tables have to be bidirectional in this layout.

Comment: Ok thx, by chance I realized this myself as well. Somehow, I am getting different results in my data base. Any idea how this can come about?

Comment: @AlexisOlson Could you please have another look. I am rather despearte and it must be something silly I do not understand about the data modeling. I tried to simplify the MWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is what you're after:

[image: Matrix]

I've defined these measures as

```
SumX = SUMX ( Main_Table, RELATED ( End_Table_X[X] ) )

SumY = SUMX ( Main_Table, RELATED ( End_Table_Y[Y] ) )
```

This solution does not require a year column on the `Bridge_Table` or bidirectional filters with the end tables.

[image: Model Diagram]

Instead of trying to propagate the year, it iterates over all of the rows of the `Main_Table` (within the local filter context) and essentially does a lookup of X or Y for each row.

Comment: thx this definetly works for my MWE, but some it does not work for my original problem. I have no clue why. I added the data model for my original data base and the dax formular that I am using. When I try to add the dax formular in my original report, he does not prompt the table 'at_sonstiges' in the related command.

Comment: Your 'original problem' is pretty different than your MWE. You've changed a bidirectional 1-to-1 relationship to a single direction 1-to-many relationship.

Comment: Oh why and how is this important? I can easily write the sql command to sum up the two columns in the table at_sonstiges. I mentioned the additional permutation of the bridge table in the text and I thought it would not change much for the MWE. Sorry

Comment: Unlike your MWE, you can't use `RELATED` from `unternehmen` to `at_sonstiges` since the relationship between `unternehmen` and the bridge table isn't the same. Note: if there aren't duplicate `unternehmen_id` in the bridge table, then you can sum over that table instead. If that doesnt' work, I suggest you create a new question with a representative MWE.

Comment: thx `sumx(unternehmensarten; RELATED(at_sonstiges[abschluss_aktuell]))` actually returns the correct result. I am just wondering why I should not have duplicated `unternehmen_id` . They are duplicate because the refer to the `unternehmen` table because I can have different types (`betreiber_typ`)