# Database modelling remove bridge table

Tags: sql-server, database, powerbi, data-modeling

I have designed a database with some outside help and I am thinking about a major change to the database model because of a problem creating reports in Power BI I have recently encountered here: [SQL Power BI Report with Bridge Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65197622/power-bi-report-with-bridge-table)

Disclaimer: if I could ask anyone within my firm, I would, but I can't.

We have a three-layer structure

1. A main table `Firms`, with information about the year and unique key/name for each firm
2. A bridge table `Firm_Bridge` which information about the type of the firm linked to `Firm_Types`
3. Many end Tables with information about sales and stuff

For these end tables, there are two types

- **Single type tables** that only matter for one Type (`End_Table_Type_A` or `End_Table_Type_B`) (often the case)
- **Multi type tables** that matter for more than one type (`End_Table_Type_all`) (rarely the case)

This is a made-up example similar to the real model

[image: Complex Model]

I am wondering if it was better to simplify this structure and directly connect the single type end tables to the firm table. I can still use the bridge table to document the type of firm and also connect the End_Table_Type_All to the firm's table. I imaging like this.

[image: Simple Model]

I hope this would avoid the problem that I have in my other question when summarizing stuff of end tables across years from `Firms` and reduce the complexity of our data model, as most tables are only single type end tables. I can exclude one join for most queries.

I am afraid I am missing something and that the current way is the proper way to model this.

What would happen in the changed model if I were to join the 'Firm_Type' to 'Firms' and then the single Type end table 'End_Table_Type_A'. Would it fetch the single end type table for each type?

Then, my idea would be stupid and I need to find another solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give this closure. It seems to be indeed a stupid idea, because I would duplicate rows connected to the end tables, as soon as I merge the information of the type with the Firms table.