# Power BI Aggregation of End Tables

Tags: sql-server, database, powerbi, report, data-modeling

I am new to Power BI and data-base management and I want clarify for myself how Power BI works in reference to my last two questions ([Database modelling Bridge Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347482/database-modelling-remove-bridge-table) , [Power BI Report Bridge Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65197622/power-bi-report-with-bridge-table) ). I have a `main_table` with firm specific information each year which is connected to an `end_table` that contains some quantitative information (e.g. sales data). The tables are modelled as a `1:N` relationship, so that I do not have to store the same values twice, which I thought is a good thing to do in data modelling.

I want to aggregate the `value` column of `end table` over the group column `Year`. I am surprised that to my understanding Power BI sums up the `value` column within the end table when I would expect the aggregation over the group variable in the connected tables

My basic example is based on this data and data model (you need to adjust the relationship manually):

```
main_table<-data.frame(id=1:20, FK_id=sample(1:2,20, replace=TRUE), Jahre=2016:2020)         
main_table<-rbind(main_table,data.frame(id=21:25, FK_id=sample(2:3,5, replace=TRUE), Jahre=2015) )
end_table<-data.frame(id=1:3, value=c(10,20,30))
```

[image: Data model]

The first 5 rows of the data including all columns looks like this:

[image: raw data]

If I take out all row specific information and sum up over `value`. It will always show the sum of the end table, which is 60, in each `Year`.

[image: Sum one directional]

Making the connection bi-directional does not help. It just sums up for the existing values of the `end_table` in each year. I get the correct results, if I add the value column to the main table using `Related value = RELATED(end_table[value])`

[image: Bi directional and correct table]

I am just wondering if there is another way to model or analyse this `1:N` relationship in Power BI. This comes up frequently and it feels a bit tedious to always add the column using `Related()` in the main table while it would be intuitive to just click both columns and expect the aggregation to be based on the grouping variable.
In any case, just asking this and my other two questions helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a weird modeling situation (even though it's not terribly uncommon). In general, it's handy to [build star schemas](https://radacad.com/power-bi-basics-of-modeling-star-schema-and-how-to-build-it) where you have dimension tables in 1:N relationships to fact table(s). E.g.

[image: Star Schema]

In this setup, the items from the dimension tables (e.g. year or customer) are used in the columns and rows in a visual and measures generally aggregate columns from the fact table (e.g. sales amount).

---

Your example inverts this. You are trying to sum over a column in your end table using the year as a dimension. As a result, it's not automatically behaving as you'd expect.

In order to get the result that you want, where `Year` is treated as a dimension, you need to write a measure that sums over `Year` as if it were a dimension. Since `main_table` is essentially a dimension table for `Year` (one unique row per year), you can write

```
SumValue = SUMX ( main_table, RELATED ( end_table[value] ) )
```

Comment: Thank you. Our project models a questionnaire and mixes snowflake and star schema. I have two levels: the first for firms and years and the second for different types of firms. At each level, a main table keeps track of this. The end tables model some grouped questions where it was difficult to structure them further using dimensional tables and hence the `1:N` relationship, e.g. for a some Yes/No questions. I have other fact tables with dimensional tables, like your example, that are also connecet to the main table and then results are as expected. So I just have to live with this.

Comment: Yeah, reality often requires suboptimal modeling structures, which means you have to be more sophisticated when writing measures.

Comment: OK just to understand what would happen if I changed the structure. For instance, I have 5 `bit` questions. Currently I save the given permutation in an end table and assign an `id` and create the `1:N` relationship. The other way would be to point back to the main table and always save the 5 answers and have a `1:1` relationship pointing to the `id` of the main table. Wouldnt that use up more space and be less efficient?

Comment: In general, you should favor usability and clean modeling over saving space. Power BI has good data compression techniques that work really well for handling redundant data (in fact, sometimes it's *more* efficient to make tables larger). I wouldn't try to optimize your model for efficiency without having a decent understanding of how it works internally.